# Tangent vectors as derivations and dot product

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, partial-derivative

Take $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean metric to be the manifold of interest for this question. Suppose we have two vectors

$v_p = v^i (\partial/\partial x^i)_p$ and

$w_p = w^j (\partial/\partial x^j)_p$

How is the dot product between $v_p$ and $w_p$ defined and what does it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euclidean metric is the following

$$ ds^2=\sum_{k=1}^n dx_k\otimes dx_k,$$

where $n$ clearly is the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So $ds^2(v_p,w_p)=\big(\sum_{k=1}^n dx_k\otimes dx_k\big)(v^i\partial_i,w^j\partial_j)=\sum_{k=1}^n dx_k(v^i\partial_i)dx_k(w^i\partial_j)$;

where $dx_k(v^i\partial_i)=\delta_{ik}v^i$ and $dx_k(w^j\partial_j)=\delta_{jk}w^j$.

Then you have
$$ds^2(v_p,w_p)=\sum_{k=1}^n v^kw^k.$$

Answer (score 1):

Just like on $\Bbb{R}^n$: $v_p \cdot w_p = \sum_{i = 1}^n v^i w^i$.

This comes directly from the isomorphism between $T_p M$ and $\Bbb{R}^n$ given by $v_p \mapsto (v^1, \dotsc, v^n)$.

Comment: Since we have the isomorphism we can make the identification: $e_i$ <---------> $\partial/\partial x^i$. $e_i \dot e_j = \delta^ij$ But given a coordinate system $(x^1, ..., x^n)$ we have $\partial x^jl/\partial x^i = \delta^{ij}$ If we were to write $(\partial/\partial x^i )(\partial/\partial x^j) x^k $that would be zero in all cases because the first operation would give 0 or 1 and the second operation would give 0 because it would be applied to a constant function (being the 0 or 1).

Comment: @jeo15 I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying (partly because of the typos). Also, what is your point with $(\partial/\partial x^i) \cdot (\partial/\partial x^j) x^k$? That's just a fancy way to denote the function $M \to \Bbb{R}$ which is equal to $x^k$ if $i = j$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: My point is that when you apply the partial derivatives to a coordinate curve twice you get zero but when you dot two unit vectors, say, $e_1\dot e_1$ you get 1 (which you should).

Comment: What does applying derivations to a function have to do with the dot product? Since the dot product is defined only between tangent vectors at the same point, the only way to interpret $(\partial / \partial x^i) \cdot (\partial / \partial x^j) x^k$ is as $c_{ij} x^k$, where $c_{ij} := (\partial / \partial x^i) \cdot (\partial / \partial x^j) = \delta^{ij}$ is a constant.